# Is there a way to tell android to always take the latest gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle

In my `gradle.build`, generated for me by Eclipse, I had

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
 }
```

Now there was a serious issue with the `0.4` version (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/_pB-fsNZapM/Ogcamgw-X9wJ) so I had to change `gradle.build` to use `0.4.2` where it has been fixed:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
 }
```

Is there a way, though, to tell in the `gradle.build` to always pick up the latest possible android gradle plugin version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use ranges as it is [supported by modern ivy versions](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html).

Using *latest.release* instead of a fixed version should do in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a version number you can supply a +. It works as a wildcard.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.+'

will take the latest until 0.5.0 comes out.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.+'

will take the latest until 1.0.0 comes out.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

will always take the latest.